# Solving a non-linear 2nd order D.E.: $y''=\sqrt y$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Struggling to solve the following differential equation: $$\frac{\Bbb d^2y}{\Bbb dx^2}=\sqrt y$$

Would appreciate some advice! It’s been several years since I did calculus. I’m reading a paper that cites this D.E. but the solution to this isn’t walked through and I’m struggling to understand the solutions.

Tried substituting but got stuck. My working thus far:

$$\frac{\Bbb d^2y}{\Bbb dx^2} - \sqrt y = 0$$

Let $v=\sqrt y$

$$\implies \ \frac{\Bbb dy}{\Bbb dx} =2v \left( \frac{\Bbb dv}{\Bbb dx} \right)$$

$$\implies \ \frac{\Bbb d^2y}{\Bbb dx^2} = 2\left( \frac{\Bbb dv}{\Bbb dx} \right) \left( \frac{\Bbb dv}{\Bbb dx} \right) +2v \left( \frac{\Bbb d^2y}{\Bbb dx^2} \right)$$

Substituting back into the original D.E.:

$$2\left(\frac{\Bbb dv}{\Bbb dx}\right)\left(\frac{\Bbb dv}{\Bbb dx}\right)+2v\left(\frac{\Bbb d^2y}{\Bbb dx^2}\right) - v=0$$

At this point I got stuck because of how to deal with the $\left(\frac{\Bbb dv}{\Bbb dx}\right)\left(\frac{\Bbb dv}{\Bbb dx}\right)$ in the first term.

Thanks in advance for the help!!

Comment: You should not have $2(\frac{dv}{dx})(\frac{dv}{dx})$, it should be just $2\frac{dv}{dx}$

Comment: Multiply both sides by $y'$.

Comment: Ahhhh thank you - silly error doing product rule by me!

Comment: `DSolve[{y''[x] == Sqrt[y[x]]}, y[x], x]`  Mathematica can't find one explicit solution.

$\text{Solve}\left[\frac{y(x)^2 \left(1+\frac{4 y(x)^{3/2}}{3 c_1}\right) \, _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{2}{3};\frac{5}{3};-\frac{4 y(x)^{3/2}}{3 c_1}\right){}^2}{\frac{4}{3} y(x)^{3/2}+c_1}=(x+c_2){}^2,y(x)\right]$

Comment: Do you have a specific set of initial/boundary conditions?

Answer (score 1):

Following Átila's suggestion, one can reduce the ODE to a quadrature:
\begin{align}
y''=\sqrt{y} &\implies y'y''=\sqrt{y}y' \\
&\implies  \frac{1}{2}(y')^2=\frac{2}{3}y^{3/2}+C_1 \\
&\implies y'=\pm\sqrt{\frac{4}{3}y^{3/2}+C} \\
&\implies \int_{y_0}^y\frac{ds}{\sqrt{\frac{4}{3}s^{3/2}+C}}=\pm(x-x_0).
\end{align}